# capistrano set and get environment variables from config to rake

Tags: ruby, variables, task, capistrano, environment

I am trying to define an environment variable in /config/deploy/staging.rb like :

```
set :default_env, { 
  'environment' => 'preprodv1'
}
```

Then I am trying to acces this variable in my file /lib/capistrano/tasks/build.rake like :

```
desc "Builds the admin front-end"
    task :build_admin_front do
        on roles (:all) do |host|
            within "#{release_path}" do
                execute "cd #{release_path}/front_admin && npm install && npm run-script build --env=#{fetch(:environment)}"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But I got this error : undefined local variable or method `environment'

Do you please have any idea of the reason why? 
Can't I access to my environment variable set in rb file from my rake file ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I don't think `fetch` will access the environment (although I could be wrong). To access an environment variable, `ENV['environment']` should work. In order to get `fetch(:environment)` working, you need `set :environment, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, I finally got it fixed by using set `:environment, "preprodv1"` Instead of set `:default_env`, `{ 'environment' => 'preprodv1' }` And by keeping `#{fetch(:environment)}` Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you’ve set the variable as `:default_env`, but you’re asking for it as `:environment`?

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax, but when i read the documentation, I see that I can only set some defined variables : [documentation](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/).
But I am not sure how to access to default_env variables, do you think that I should try something like `#{fetch(:default_env.environment)}` ? 
I havn't found the correct syntax in the documentation

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re doing it right looking at the docs. Very odd.

Comment: I am gonna keep looking for a solution, thank you for your help @Thomas

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(:default_env)['environment']
```

Comment: I think that I was mixing two syntaxes :
`set :default_env, { 
  'environment' => 'preprodv1'
}` is accessible with :
`fetch(:default_env)['environment']`
and 
`set :environment` is accessible with : 
`fetch(:environment)`